# Rest API asyncio gets stuck while running

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, cryptocurrency, ccxt

Can anyone help me with Rest API asynchronous? I used Asyncio for 4 requests to FTX server. If I run the code, it prints 'balance','position','chart1','chart2' and stops working. It doesn't incur any errors but it seems to get stuck somewhere, probably during the requests. How can I fix this issue?

```
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt
import asyncio
import FTXdata

api_key = "api_key "
secret  = "api_secret "

ftx = ccxt.ftx(config={
    'apiKey': api_key, 
    'secret': secret,
    })

symbols = {'DOT-PERP':'DOT-PERP'}
       

    #1    
async def balance():
    print('balance')
    balance = await ftx.fetch_balance()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    #2
async def position(exchange, symbol):
    print('position')
    position= await exchange.fetch_positions(symbol)         
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    #3
async def dataframe(exchange, symbol):
    print('chart1')    
    data = await exchange.fetch_ohlcv(
        symbol=symbol,               
        timeframe='5m', 
        since=None, 
        limit=100)    
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    #4
async def dataframe1h(exchange, symbol):
    print('chart2') 
    data1h = await exchange.fetch_ohlcv(
        symbol=symbol,               
        timeframe='1h', 
        since=None, 
        limit=30)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main(exchange,symbol):
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(balance())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(position(exchange, symbol))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(dataframe(exchange, symbol))
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(dataframe1h(exchange, symbol))
    await asyncio.wait([task1,task2,task3,task4])
    print('finish')

op_mode = False

while True: 
    for symbol in symbols: 
    asyncio.run(main(ftx,symbol))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code a bit and it works fine now. I've added some prints of the variables received so you can see the data.

Remember that `asyncio` works *asynchronously* so the order the data is printed in the console might not always be the same way it is ordered in your code since `asyncio` is waiting to receive the data before it can do anything with it.

```
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt
import asyncio

api_key = '...'
secret  = '...'

ftx = ccxt.ftx(config={
    'apiKey': api_key, 
    'secret': secret,
    })

symbols = {'DOT-PERP':'DOT-PERP'}
       
    #1    
async def balance():
    balance = await ftx.fetch_balance()
    print('balance')
    print(balance)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    #2
async def position(exchange, symbol):
    position = await exchange.fetch_positions(symbol)
    print('position')
    print(position)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    #3
async def dataframe(exchange, symbol):
    data = await exchange.fetch_ohlcv(
        symbol=symbol,               
        timeframe='5m', 
        since=None, 
        limit=100)
    print('chart1')
    print(data)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    #4
async def dataframe1h(exchange, symbol): 
    data1h = await exchange.fetch_ohlcv(
        symbol=symbol,               
        timeframe='1h', 
        since=None, 
        limit=30)
    print('chart2')
    print(data1h)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main(exchange,symbol):
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(balance())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(position(exchange, symbol))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(dataframe(exchange, symbol))
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(dataframe1h(exchange, symbol))
    await asyncio.wait([task1,task2,task3,task4])
    print('finish')

op_mode = False

while True: 
    for symbol in symbols: 
        asyncio.run(main(ftx,symbol))
```

One thing to note is that you are not working with the REST API here but with `websockets` which works a lot better with `asyncio`. I will amend your question for greater accuracy.